# when creating table - "JSON encoding failed: Malformed UTF-8 characters, possibly incorrectly encoded" in phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

When i create a table in PHPmyAdmin i get the message

> "JSON encoding failed: Malformed UTF-8 characters, possibly
>   incorrectly encoded"

I have not added any contents to the table and there are four columns in it

```
Id        - VarChar - 10     - primary key
mcode     - Varchar - 100
pname     - Varchar - 5000
datevalue - Varchar - 100
```

The code is given below -

```
CREATE TABLE catalog.test_table ( 
  first_col VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL , 
  second_col VARCHAR(5000) NOT NULL , 
  third_col VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL , 
  id INT(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT , 
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
) ENGINE = InnoDB;
```